# pvd: time series with multiple datasets

Tags: dataset, paraview

I am using `.pvd` file to load multiple files to Paraviw simultaneously. The file looks like this for time-series with a a single dataset:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="Collection" version="0.1">
  <Collection>
    <DataSet timestep="0" file="a.1.vtu"/>
    <DataSet timestep="1" file="a.2.vtu"/>
  </Collection>
</VTKFile>
```

I would like to specify other files to be loaded along with `a.*.vtu` (e.g. `b.*.vtp`) which will show up as another item in the pipeline browser.

I tried to put multiple `<Collection>` blocks to the `.vtp`, but Paraview loads only one of them. I also tried using `group` and `part` attributes to `<DataSet>`, without any result.

How can I achieve having separate datasets (all of them saved at the same points in time) in one `.pvd` file?

Comment: Can you not just have two .pvd files, one each for `a.*.vtu` and `b.*.vtu`? Then you can just load both .pvd files into ParaView. Is there anything stopping you doing this, do you need or just want a single single .pvd?

Comment: Nice idea, thanks. Unfortunately I need to pass all that to Paraview on the command-line, but the `--data` option may not be repeated when invoking Paraview :| So it seems I need one single file.

Comment: From your example file it seems that your files are part of a timeseries. ParaView allows you to specify a series of files using the `--data` command line argument by replacing a numeral in the file names with a dot, `.`. See [this ParaView wiki page](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Users_Guide/Command_line_arguments#Executable_help). So you could have muiltiple files and call ParaView with the option --data=a..vtk` (note the double dots - your files will have to be called a1.vtk, a2.vtk, ... aN.vtk).

Comment: There are multiple datasets, and each dataset is saved at the same points in time (some are `.vtu`, some are `.vtp`). I would have to specify multiple ``--data``, which does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. To create separate items in the pipeline browser, you need to open separate files i.e. create separate pvd files for a.*.vtu and b.*.vtu with same timestep values and the UI will still load the same timestep at a time from both the files when playing animations etc.

Comment: Is this still the case for multiple datasets?

Comment: yes, multiple disconnected datasets need multiple pvd files. You still cannot put them in the same one. You can open a.pvd and b.pvd simultaneously, however.